# how can I send POST requests to some web page with manipulation of the current page?

Tags: php, security, http, post, header

I want to set headers like post variable name and the value and send and expect response.
this is also a security question, assume I want to send post a form variables of which are action="delete" and userid=100, and lets say, I have found a file which accepts ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)** is your friend! :)

Say you've noticed an endpoint at `example.org/process.php` that a form is posting to. You can tailor you own custom request easily from the command line using `curl`.

```
$ curl -X POST --data "action=delete&userid=100" example.org/process.php
```

The `--data` or `-D` flag lets you pass arbitrary POST data just as an HTML form would. You can also set HTTP request headers with equal ease:

```
$ curl --header "User-Agent: Mosaic" example.org/process.php
```

You can see exactly what's happening with the `-v` (for verbose) flag. For the first example above the output is:

```
* About to connect() to example.org port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.0.43.10... connected
* Connected to example.org (192.0.43.10) port 80 (#0)
> POST /process.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.5.0) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0d zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.22
> Host: example.org
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 24
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 302 Found
< Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
< Server: BigIP
* HTTP/1.0 connection set to keep alive!
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.org left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

If you're using a *NIX operating system including Mac OS X, you probably already have `curl`, just open a shell. If you work with Ruby at all, I highly recommend [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb), a set of bindings for that language. Most PHP installations come with curl support, although the interface is pretty horrible. The docs are over at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for this. Check about [more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

You can send data POST/GET method, upload file, SSL support, cookie support, ftp support and much more

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at Snoopy (http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/)

Its a PHP class designed to act as a web browser with lots of useful functionality like simulating HTTP requests, manipulating form data etc.